# Where are apps natively stored on a Nook running CM7 off a micro SD

Tags: external-sd, nook-color

I have a Nook running cm7 off a class 2 4gb sandisk. I've installed a couple of Apps on my device. I've noticed, after going to managing apps, that some apps are actually being installed internally and some apps being installed onto the SD card. I am planning to upgrade to a class 4 16gb sandisk, and I want to completely start fresh, how do I remove pre-existing apps internally? I'm slightly confused. Thanks.

edit:

Actually, so I guess [verygreens](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1000957) method splits the SD card into 2. The first "internal (1gb)", second being the "rest of the sd ( total sd - 1gb)". So..to my understanding, apps defaults to installing "internally" or the first partition, how can I make it so it defaults to the larger partition? Or do I need to manually move it after each install of a new application?

Answer (score 1):

I would just repartition the SD card so that the first partition is larger.  AFAIK the system doesn't rely only the partition size, just the order.

You could, however, run `su` then `pm setInstallLocation 2` in a terminal on the device, or from adb shell, assuming you have root.  That will make installs default to the "SD card", your second partition.

Answer (score 0):

Apps are stored in the .android directory of your card. The . means it is hiddden on Unix systems :)