# How to ensure app installed on SD card stays on SD card after an update

Tags: updates, external-sd, internal-sd

I have noticed that apps I have moved to the SD card (external storage) when updated get moved back to the device (internal storage).  Is there a way on a non-rooted device to ensure the updated app stays on the external storage?

Comment: If you're rooted, try the second part of my answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/12633/1465).