# How do I change the storage directory for Playstore apps in a device running lollipop?

Tags: samsung, internal-storage, external-sd, hardware, storage

Just wanted to change my storage directory from internal storage to SD card, unfortunately , I am unable to do this.Could anyone provide a solution ? The device I am using is Samsung Tab S running lollipop!

Comment: Are you rooted?  See http://android.stackexchange.com/a/12633/1465

Comment: No, my device isn't rooted.